# Saving parts of URL information for reuse in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can one take the information of a URL?

I want to use the appended information on this URL `http://localhost:3000/transaction?transactionId=72U8ALPE` in a fetch API.

I am trying to take the value **72U8ALPE** and save it to state or as a variable. Then use if on the URL I will use on a fetch request. For example

`https://google.com/${the-url-last-part-saved-as-variable-or-in-state}`

Comment: Would you mind clarify your precise question? Is it only how to obtain the value from the URL? Or also how to pass it from one React lifecycle event to another, or from one component to another? Or how to execute a Fetch? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the query parameters from the `URL` object.
This could look something like this:

```js
let currentUrl = new URL(window.location);
let transactionId = currentUrl.searchParams.get('transactionId');
```

You can then use the variable to append to your HTTP request.